# CNN model interpretation

Tags: python

I have a hyperspectral image having dimension m * m * L where m*m is the spatial size and L denotes the number of signals.

Now the shape of my image array is: (1, 64, 64, 91) where 1 is the number of examples, 64 is the length and width of the image and 91 is no. of channels of the image.

I have trained the image with CNN and got the result but I want to use the silency map to get the explainable outcome. Most of the Silency map, I see the image is in RGB with 3 channels but in my case, I have 91 channels. So, how can I use any of the explainable CNN features?